Angular/PrimeNG/PrimeFlex - Left and Right Panel Heights Hidden Beyond Card Body
I am working on an Angular project using PrimeNG components, and I'm facing an issue where the left and right panels of a p-card are extending beyond the height of the card body and getting hidden. I'm using the p-splitter component to divide the page into three sections (20%, 60%, 20%). The center section contains a p-card that should fit within the viewport, but the left and right panels (which are supposed to be scrollable and occupy 50% of the card's width each) are extending beyond and getting hidden.
GitHub Repository: To assist in troubleshooting, I have made a minimal reproducible example available on GitHub. You can clone the repository, install dependencies, and run the project using the following commands:
git clone https://github.com/kashif-khan/PrimeNgAngular.git
cd PrimeNgAngular
npm install
npm start


What I've tried:

Adding p-scrollpanel to the panels
Using overflow-y-auto and overflow-y-scroll on the c-content div
Setting h-screen and h-full classes to try to control the height

Here's the relevant part of my HTML structure:
<div class="flex flex-column h-screen">
  <div class="text-5xl flex align-items-center justify-content-center site-nav border-1">This is navbar</div>
  <div class="site-content">
    <p-splitter [panelSizes]="[20, 60, 20]" styleClass="m-0 p-0 h-full">
      <ng-template pTemplate>
        <div class="col flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-5xl text-white">
          Panel 1
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate>
        <div class="col flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-5xl text-white">
          <p-card header="Card header" subheader="Card Subheader" [ngClass]="['h-full', 'w-full']"
            styleClass="flex h-full w-full bg-green-400 c-content-scroll">
            <ng-template pTemplate="header">
              <div class="flex justify-content-between p-2">
                <p-button label="Float left" severity="secondary" />
                <p-button label="Float right" />
              </div>
            </ng-template>
            <div class="c-content">
              <div class="flex">
                <div class="w-6 h-screen border-1 bg-red-400 overflow-y-scroll">
                  <h1>Left Panel</h1>
                  <h2>This should be a scrollable content area with 50% width of the card.</h2>
                  Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos minus aperiam officiis at, recusandae tenetur veniam! Necessitatibus, ad dolore! Quis itaque possimus laborum magni impedit, quae culpa, accusamus esse tempora iste laudantium, rerum debitis quos neque? Exercitationem, debitis illum eos voluptatum beatae corporis accusantium eaque eveniet temporibus vero obcaecati dolore excepturi doloribus omnis veniam animi perspiciatis dolorem tempore. Iure exercitationem qui nisi ipsum vero officiis voluptatibus adipisci eligendi nemo. Quam, sapiente cumque a, illum facere fugiat hic facilis quod quaerat sequi voluptatum nihil praesentium distinctio labore voluptate magni consectetur qui voluptatem corporis laborum blanditiis delectus. Dolorem sunt error expedita nesciunt consequatur praesentium accusantium ab, quos et, quasi dolore cumque atque, aliquam inventore a! Impedit maiores rem obcaecati rerum asperiores quas esse ea odio provident recusandae. Officia sint quas suscipit architecto totam dolor id voluptatum numquam laborum quidem animi soluta, ratione obcaecati tempora facilis harum, vel et. Maiores in voluptatum quasi, quidem iusto aliquam, illo veniam omnis consequatur laudantium ipsa itaque excepturi cumque! Facilis ratione tempora nihil praesentium, quibusdam adipisci, molestiae, magnam amet rem aut at consequatur omnis numquam sed ut impedit possimus eum dolores in quos ex? Laboriosam, ab quidem omnis repellendus eum quos eligendi in tempora consequuntur excepturi numquam quae id accusamus ducimus eos suscipit cumque obcaecati eveniet inventore iusto officia rerum? Iste vitae quaerat eveniet quam odit molestias natus in. Quae cupiditate aperiam provident neque sunt repellendus dignissimos architecto excepturi asperiores consequuntur ipsum blanditiis quo ex ratione minima error vitae id maxime natus, unde a, ducimus culpa ullam. Deserunt repudiandae provident debitis, tempora illum libero delectus laborum eos quam totam earum obcaecati, dolore architecto veritatis accusamus culpa soluta praesentium nulla perferendis aspernatur mollitia eaque corporis facilis. Ducimus nesciunt recusandae ipsa doloremque, et dicta quasi voluptatum blanditiis quisquam minima iste nemo vitae aspernatur ad explicabo quia dolorem amet quos! Eius, officiis mollitia est temporibus ea rem labore cupiditate perferendis cum. Modi in quod temporibus officiis soluta reprehenderit odit autem mollitia, et dolorum consequatur, sed nobis magni vel! Doloremque eos in eaque fugiat distinctio dolore doloribus quis tempore. Beatae delectus sequi laboriosam neque quo dolores labore, mollitia ea rem esse. Veritatis ab adipisci dolore consequatur pariatur error qui cumque, nemo eum neque id sequi est perferendis repellendus debitis vitae placeat eveniet quo eius. Delectus expedita rem quod iure porro minima distinctio, modi, illo magnam tenetur, quasi alias amet laudantium numquam illum quisquam odio ratione ab nostrum voluptate natus. Aspernatur minima animi ducimus libero aliquam obcaecati, commodi id, cum explicabo ad laudantium cumque quis? Recusandae laboriosam soluta nam impedit odio officia dolores amet cum, enim sit distinctio at veritatis reprehenderit. Exercitationem expedita sint reprehenderit sunt magnam, optio vero alias aliquid distinctio dolorem quaerat hic modi enim doloremque? Magni, vel temporibus suscipit alias et cumque ratione ex nihil numquam beatae soluta error voluptates laboriosam minima sequi voluptatum. Labore voluptatum quae dolore odio voluptates perferendis libero quaerat eum ratione voluptatibus amet a dignissimos et modi illo quia, inventore qui vel aperiam quasi sunt incidunt! Exercitationem sunt, reprehenderit quos impedit vero facere illum dicta!
                </div>
                <div class="w-6 h-screen border-1 bg-blue-400 overflow-y-scroll">
                  <h1>Right Panel</h1>
                  <h2>This should be a scrollable content area with 50% width of the card.</h2>
                  Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos minus aperiam officiis at, recusandae tenetur veniam! Necessitatibus, ad dolore! Quis itaque possimus laborum magni impedit, quae culpa, accusamus esse tempora iste laudantium, rerum debitis quos neque? Exercitationem, debitis illum eos voluptatum beatae corporis accusantium eaque eveniet temporibus vero obcaecati dolore excepturi doloribus omnis veniam animi perspiciatis dolorem tempore. Iure exercitationem qui nisi ipsum vero officiis voluptatibus adipisci eligendi nemo. Quam, sapiente cumque a, illum facere fugiat hic facilis quod quaerat sequi voluptatum nihil praesentium distinctio labore voluptate magni consectetur qui voluptatem corporis laborum blanditiis delectus. Dolorem sunt error expedita nesciunt consequatur praesentium accusantium ab, quos et, quasi dolore cumque atque, aliquam inventore a! Impedit maiores rem obcaecati rerum asperiores quas esse ea odio provident recusandae. Officia sint quas suscipit architecto totam dolor id voluptatum numquam laborum quidem animi soluta, ratione obcaecati tempora facilis harum, vel et. Maiores in voluptatum quasi, quidem iusto aliquam, illo veniam omnis consequatur laudantium ipsa itaque excepturi cumque! Facilis ratione tempora nihil praesentium, quibusdam adipisci, molestiae, magnam amet rem aut at consequatur omnis numquam sed ut impedit possimus eum dolores in quos ex? Laboriosam, ab quidem omnis repellendus eum quos eligendi in tempora consequuntur excepturi numquam quae id accusamus ducimus eos suscipit cumque obcaecati eveniet inventore iusto officia rerum? Iste vitae quaerat eveniet quam odit molestias natus in. Quae cupiditate aperiam provident neque sunt repellendus dignissimos architecto excepturi asperiores consequuntur ipsum blanditiis quo ex ratione minima error vitae id maxime natus, unde a, ducimus culpa ullam. Deserunt repudiandae provident debitis, tempora illum libero delectus laborum eos quam totam earum obcaecati, dolore architecto veritatis accusamus culpa soluta praesentium nulla perferendis aspernatur mollitia eaque corporis facilis. Ducimus nesciunt recusandae ipsa doloremque, et dicta quasi voluptatum blanditiis quisquam minima iste nemo vitae aspernatur ad explicabo quia dolorem amet quos! Eius, officiis mollitia est temporibus ea rem labore cupiditate perferendis cum. Modi in quod temporibus officiis soluta reprehenderit odit autem mollitia, et dolorum consequatur, sed nobis magni vel! Doloremque eos in eaque fugiat distinctio dolore doloribus quis tempore. Beatae delectus sequi laboriosam neque quo dolores labore, mollitia ea rem esse. Veritatis ab adipisci dolore consequatur pariatur error qui cumque, nemo eum neque id sequi est perferendis repellendus debitis vitae placeat eveniet quo eius. Delectus expedita rem quod iure porro minima distinctio, modi, illo magnam tenetur, quasi alias amet laudantium numquam illum quisquam odio ratione ab nostrum voluptate natus. Aspernatur minima animi ducimus libero aliquam obcaecati, commodi id, cum explicabo ad laudantium cumque quis? Recusandae laboriosam soluta nam impedit odio officia dolores amet cum, enim sit distinctio at veritatis reprehenderit. Exercitationem expedita sint reprehenderit sunt magnam, optio vero alias aliquid distinctio dolorem quaerat hic modi enim doloremque? Magni, vel temporibus suscipit alias et cumque ratione ex nihil numquam beatae soluta error voluptates laboriosam minima sequi voluptatum. Labore voluptatum quae dolore odio voluptates perferendis libero quaerat eum ratione voluptatibus amet a dignissimos et modi illo quia, inventore qui vel aperiam quasi sunt incidunt! Exercitationem sunt, reprehenderit quos impedit vero facere illum dicta!
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <ng-template pTemplate="footer">
              <div class="flex justify-content-between p-2">
                <p-button label="Float left" severity="secondary" />
                <p-button label="Float right" />
              </div>
            </ng-template>
          </p-card>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate>
        <div class="col flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-5xl text-white">
          Panel 3
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </p-splitter>
  </div>
</div>

And the relevant CSS:
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css";
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.css";
@import "primeflex/primeflex.css";

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.site-nav {
  min-height: 10%;
}
.site-content {
  height: 90%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.c-content-scroll {
  position: relative;
}
.c-content-scroll .p-card-header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.c-content-scroll .p-card-body {
  height: calc(100% - 150px);
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 75px;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.c-content-scroll .p-card-footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

How can I adjust my CSS or structure so that the left and right panels fit within the height of the card body and do not extend beyond it?
